# Sliding Drawer/View with midpoint (swipe up/down from midpoint)

Tags: android

I'm quite new to android and development in general. I want to create a view that I can swipe up or down from a midpoint on the screen. I was trying to modify Sliding Drawer to do that but without success. Actually I don't know what to change to add that functionality. Something like the "swipe down to unlock" thing, but it should be able to swipe up as well. Every information, direction or any help will be very appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This should better help you! It is a great library!
https://github.com/SimonVT/android-menudrawer